# How to unit test JSON result in Jest NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, unit-testing, jestjs

my function i am trying to unit test is given as

**NOTE** :   `mypayload= payload.Items` i will give a JSON reference at the end of the question

```
function setIdtoDeviceIdIfEmptyAndSetNullIfFieldEmpty(mypayload) {
      let _res = mypayload.map(ele => {
        if (ele.id == null) {
          ele.id = ele.deviceId
        }
        if (ele.id == null && ele.deviceId == null) {
          ele.id = '***Both id and device id is null***'
        }
        if (ele.ssid == null) {
          ele.ssid = '***ssid is null***'
        }
        if (ele.deviceName == null) {
          ele.deviceName = '**deviceName is null**'
        }
        return ele;
      })
      return _res
    }
```

I am trying to test the **most basic part** that is the first if loop `ele.id==null`

I have tried :

```
describe('Test setIdtoDeviceIdIfEmptyAndSetNullIfFieldEmpty', () => {
        test('testing null', () => {
            index.setIdtoDeviceIdIfEmptyAndSetNullIfFieldEmpty(mypayload)
            mypayload.map(ele => {
                if (ele.id == null) {
                    expect(ele.id).toEqual(ele.deviceId)
                }
            })
        })
    })
```

However i cannot get this test case to fail for ex if i enter `expect(ele.id).toEqual("random")` it still passes when i am expecting it to fail,Clearly i am doing something wrong

**Reference**

```
const payload = {"Items":[
    {
    "id" :"mycompany-00b12396",
    "ssid": "home",
    "deviceName": "mydevice",
    "time": "0.753235299 Hours"
    },
    {
        "ssid": "office",
        "deviceName": "thisdevice",
        "time": "12.52115515 Hours",
        "deviceId":"mycompany-0031f13"
    }
]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been trying and this worked for me hope it helps someone in the future

```
describe('Test setIdtoDeviceIdIfEmptyAndSetNullIfFieldEmpty', () => {
    test('testing null', () => {
        const result = index.setIdtoDeviceIdIfEmptyAndSetNullIfFieldEmpty(mypayload)
        let check = result.find(el => el.deviceId === "mycompany-00a412f");
        expect(check.id).toEqual(check.deviceId)
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You should test the result of the function like this:

```js
describe('Test setIdtoDeviceIdIfEmptyAndSetNullIfFieldEmpty', () => {
        test('testing null', () => {
            const result = index.setIdtoDeviceIdIfEmptyAndSetNullIfFieldEmpty(mypayload)
            result.map(ele => {
                if (!ele.id) {
                    expect(ele.id).toEqual(ele.deviceId)
                }
            })
        })
    })
```

Comment: Appreciate the effort,However i just tried this and it does not work :) tests are still passing when i pass `expect(ele.id).toEqual("random")`

Comment: Also a thing to note is that my function is working perfectly fine.. all outputs are as expected..

Comment: Check my edit, you should test the result of the function instead.